# javascript multi-content opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I'm having a big problem with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function opencontent(imgClass){
        imgTag = $('.'+imgClass).$('.header').('#showContent').$('img').attr('class');
        if(imgTag == 'hiden'){
            $(imgTag).val('show');
            $('.'+imgClass).$('.body').toggle();
        }else{
            $(imgTag).val('hiden');
            $('.'+imgClass).$('.body').toggle();
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="login">
<div class="header">
    <a id="showContent" onclick="opencontent('login');"><img class="hiden" align="center" src="images/hbullet.png" style="top: -4px; position: relative; left: -7px;" />Login</a>
</div>
<div class="body">
    <form method="post" target="_self">
        <input name="login_username" placeholder="Username" type="text" />
        <input name="login_password" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
        <input value="Login" type="submit" style="width: 263px;" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Basically what i want to do with this code is, having an "a" tag, with an image inside it, that on click of "a" tag it change the img class, and open/hides the body class of same time, but I must obligatory have {onclick="opencontent('login');"} code so that i may be able to use this method with the other codes i have equal to this except the code inside the body class.

Any one knows anything that works well with what I want?

Edit~

Ok problem solved this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function opencontent(imgClass){
        var clas = $('.'+imgClass+ '> .header > a > img').attr('class');
        if(clas == 'hidden'){
            clas.val('show');
            $('.'+imgClass+ '> .body').slideToggle();
        }else{
            clas.val('hide');
            $('.'+imgClass+ '> .body').slideToggle();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Check your console. There are lots of syntax errors in your code.

Comment: I know that's why I need some help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Nikato! Please take a look at stackoverflow.com/about to see the format of questions to get the best possible answers! What @PSL suggest is sensible - check your browser console, see where the syntax errors are and fix them one by one. Otherwise, start with much simpler, bare-bones code and add functionality little by little. At every step, check that it works and if a change doesn't work and you don't know why, edit your question or open another question to ask about it!